# Como puedo hacer MODIFY a una columna usando Python + SQL

Tags: sql, postgresql

aloha, estoy tratando de hacer **ALTER TABLE MODIFY** a una columna, ponerle `INT` y `AUTOINCREMENT` pero me da este error de sintaxis, YA NO tengo mente para solucionarlo.

> File "c:\Users\Eilienz13\OneDrive\Escritorio\py_conexion\main.py", line 54, in  modificarColumnas() File "c:\Users\Eilienz13\OneDrive\Escritorio\py_conexion\main.py", line 45, in modificarColumnas cursor.execute(query) psycopg2.errors.SyntaxError: error de sintaxis en o cerca de «MODIFY» LINE 1: ALTER TABLE clientes MODIFY COLUMN id INTEGER AUTOINCREMENT...

aqui parte del codigoo donde esta el conflicto

```
def crearTabla():
    cursor = connection.cursor()
    query = "Create Table clientes(id int,nombre varchar(255),telefono numeric(12),cuenta varchar(255),contraseña varchar(255),usuario varchar(255),pin numeric(4),inicio date,fin date, PRIMARY KEY (id)"
    try:
        cursor.execute(query)
    except:
        print("La tabla clientes ya existe duh, no te repitas mas ;)")
    cursor.close()


def modificarColumnas():
    cursor = connection.cursor()
    query = ' ALTER TABLE clientes MODIFY COLUMN id INTEGER AUTOINCREMENT '
    cursor.execute(query)
    print("Columna Actualizada")
    cursor.close
```

Comment: Por que no solo la creas con el auto_increment en vez de modificarla ?? lo veo innecesario el modificarla para eso. Ademas, dice que es error de sintaxis, no recuerdo que llleve COLUMN el MODIFY.

Comment: Bienvenido a Stack Overflow en español, te sugiero que hagas el [tour] y de paso ganes tu primer medalla, también es muy importante que leas [ask] para poder mejorar tu pregunta y que sea bien recibida por la comunidad mejorando así, tus chances de obtener buenas respuestas.

Comment: El error no tiene nada que ver con python es un error del motor de SQL, en cuyo caso deberías indicar con la etiquetas el motor que estás usando. Suerte.

Comment: estaba practicando con un tutorial, pero me surgio ese error y no encontraba la sintaxis correcta para solucionarlo usando postgres y psycopg2 (no me salian las etiquetas al menos de psycopg2 para ponerle a la pregunta)
quiero aprender como modificar para cuando llegue a ese paso dominarlo por eso me fui por esa via del MODIFY.

Comment: @Excorpion, sustraje el COLUMN del codigo pero me sigue el error de sintaxis.

Answer (score 0):

`MODIFY` no es una instrucción de SQL para hacer lo que quieres; se utiliza `ALTER`.

```
ALTER TABLE clientes ALTER COLUMN id TYPE INTEGER AUTOINCREMENT
```